# How to fix "pkg: Not enough space in /var/cache/pkg, needed 32mib available" error?

Tags: freebsd

I'm downloaded the latest FreeBSD version from ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/.

After the installation I wanted to install the `nginx` web server on my virtual OS (using virtualbox), so, I searched and found this:

```
pkg install nginx
```

when I executed this command, I saw the following error:

```
pkg: Not enough space in /var/cache/pkg, needed 32mib available
```

The output of `df`:

```
root@BSD:~ $ df
Filesystem  1K-blocks   Used    Avail   Capacity    Mounted on
/dev/ada0p2 1928476      1801996   -27769   102%        /
devfs       1       1   0   100%        /dev
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: So you don't get the obvious answer, please put the output of the `df` command into the body of your question.

Comment: try     pkg autoremove     or  pkg clean

Comment: I think the size of root partition (1.8G) not too big. If you don't want reinstall you can read this: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disks-growing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, given that your filesystem is 102% full (this is because of MINFREE reservation, 8% by default, see "man newfs"; basically filesystem would be totally full at 108%, but non-root users cannot fill it above 100%) you just don't have enough disk space there.

Answer (score 4):

Just resize VM disk and run

```
service growfs onestart
```